# How to integrate $\int_{c}\frac{e^{2z}}{(z+1)^4}dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to integrate $\int_{c}\frac{e^{2z}}{(z+1)^4}dz$ for $c:|z|=2$ and $c:|z-3|=1$?

My Attempt:

For $c:|z|=2$

$\int_{c}\frac{e^{2z}}{(z+1)^4}dz=\frac{2\pi i f^{(3)}(-1)}{3!}=\frac{2\pi i\times 2^{3} e^{-2}}{3!}=\frac{8\pi i}{3e^2}$

For $c:|z-3|=1$

$\int_{c}\frac{e^{2z}}{(z+1)^4}dz=0$ 
because $z=-1$ lies outside $|z-3|=1$ but I am not sure how to prove this.

Please help.

Comment: $\lvert -1 - 3 \rvert = 4 > 1$

Comment: Your work looks correct. You're unsure how to prove that -1 lies outside the circle?

Comment: @Chappers, No I mean I am not sure how to prove the integral is zero.

Comment: It's zero because the function is analytic in the circle, but I'm curious, why did you think it's zero? :)

Comment: @benji, because $z=-1$  lies outside this circle. Is that the answer or do I have to prove that this means the integral is zero?

Comment: The only singularity is at $z=-1$, outside the contour, so the function is analytic on the interior of the contour...?

Comment: @Chappers, What I mean is  the answer just to say that $z=−1$ lies outside the circle or do I have to prove the theorem?